# Wave file header endianess

Tags: c++, endianness

I am writing code in c++ to read a wave file in. I am following the wave file specification I found [here.](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

In the following code I am reading in the chunksize, which is stored in bytes 4,5,6,7.

According to the specification, this int is stores in little endian in these 4 bytes.

So if these 4 bytes held the unsigned value 2, I would think the would be as follows..

4        5        6        7
00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000

So if I am trying to read these 4 bytes as an int on windows, I don't need to do anything correct? Since windows it little endian. So this is what I did...

```
unsigned int chunk_size = (hbytes[4] << 24) + (hbytes[5] << 16) + (hbytes[6] << 8) + hbytes[7];
```

but that didn't work, it gave me an incorrect value. When I swapped the endian of the bytes, it did work....

```
unsigned int chunk_size = (hbytes[7] << 24) + (hbytes[6] << 16) + (hbytes[5] << 8) + hbytes[4];
```

Is this information I have about wavefiles correct? Is this int stored as little endian? Or are my assumptions about endianess incorrect?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but if I recall correctly from what I have read a few years back not all windows are little endian. I think it has to do with hardware manufacture of the processor that deals with the registers and instruction sets for and how the compilers (asm) treat the storage of basic data types. For example you can have a Windows on an Intel machine and Windows on an AMD machine where one could store its integers as little endian while the other as big endian.

Answer (score 0):

You got everything right except the procedure to convert a little-endian stream.

Your diagram is correct: if the 4-byte field holds a 2, then the first byte (hbytes[4]) is 2 and the remaining bytes are 0. Why would you then want to left shift that byte by 24? The byte you want to left shift by 24 is the high-order byte, hbytes[7].

Comment: I think the spacial representation in my head lead me to think about things in a confusing manner. After reader the definition of little endian, my errors are clear.

Comment: @ScottF: Many of us have a big-endian model in our head, which is why we talk about left-shifting when we mean "shift towards the high-order end". So it's easy to get confused. (I've often wondered whether people who grow up with right-to-left scripts which still write numbers with the most significant digit on the left -- arabic, for example -- have a naturally little-endian representation in their heads.) Anyway, hope the answer helped.